# Deciding if surfaces in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ are varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, projective-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ given in some very explicit way (for example given combinatorially in some triangulation of $\mathbb{C}P^2$).  Is it decidable whether or not $S$ is (smoothly, say) isotopic to some smooth complex projective curve $C$?

Comment: If $S$ is a closed complex submanifold then it is automatically a curve by GAGA (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry ). So you need the establish the existence of an integrable almost complex structure on $S$, which is compatible with the almost complex structure of ${\bf P}^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to assume $S$ is a complex submanifold though.

Comment: It is semidecidable. I suspect decidability is either false or unknown. You should ask at Mathoverflow.